# Using two GLOBAL variables with same name in PHP

Tags: php, session, get

I used `$_SESSION['user']`, i.e. user as variable to store the logged in `ID` of user in SESSION array. At the same time, I used at some other place `$_GET['user']` to do some other stuffs.

However, the problem is that as soon as I use GET array to set "user" value, my user value of SESSION array also gets over-written. I am pretty surprised at this.

The code worked exactly fine(no over-writing) at my local server, but the same failed on my website

Though, I have fixed it for now by changing the variable, I am curious to know the reason behind this.

Please comment if I am unclear in my question.

Here goes the code(posting on request). However, I don't think this was required

```
if($_SESSION['user']!=""){
$user = $_GET['user'];
$q = "select * from some_table where username='$user' order by product";
$a = mysql_query($q);
$count = mysql_num_rows($a);
if($count==0){
   die ("No such username exists. No credits will be deducted for wrong query.");
   }
   else {
   $user_q = $_SESSION['user'];
   $val = 10;
   $query2 = "UPDATE some_table set user_balance=user_balance-'$val' where username='$user_q'";
   mysql_query($query2);
   echo "<table class='tablesorter' id='myTable' style='width:600px;align:center;'><thead><tr><th align='center'>Product</th><th align='center'>Time</th><th align='center'>Credit</th><th align='center'>Modified Credits</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
   }
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($a)){
$p = $array['product_name'];
$c = $array['cost_incurred'];
$t = $array['timestamp_jkj'];
$m = $array['mod_balance_something'];
   echo "<tr><td align='center'>$p</td><td align='center' >$t</td><td  align='center'>$c</td><td  align='center'>$m</td></tr>";
   }
   echo "</tbody></table>";
}
else {
  echo "You need to login to see your details.";
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: This should not happen and you should post your code so we can try and work out why it did.

Comment: But, why it then worked with mere change in variable name from user to user1 ??

Comment: Without seeing your code, I don't know.

Comment: @PrashantSingh: May be some condition to set session variable is getting true with the account you are using locally and not with the one on remote

Comment: Hey, I echoed the $_SESSION['user'] value before and after this code snippet and the values were different, code has been added

Comment: @PrashantSingh: Do you have register_globals set to On?

Comment: How is that going to affect the values

Comment: @ShaktiSingh nopes, no chance about different users at remote and localhost. The user value was set even for non-existing ids, that means assignment is condition-less

Comment: @PrashantSingh:That comment was before viewing your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your register_globals setting is turned on. Read more about it here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/Register_Globals

Comment: +1 - But you should have added "and you should turn it off." :-)

Comment: @drrcknlsn Indeed, it's an evil setting, and also deprecated right now

Comment: +1 really nice comment. also i liked the comment of @drrcknlsn :)

Answer (score 3):

I really liked your comment "I added the code. Find OUT" @DaveRandom

Check your register_globals settings.

Thanks :)